# Getters and Setters with interfaces has a parameter

Tags: java, interface

How do i implement a getter and a setter method with interfaces as a parameter?

I have a class test that implements an Test interface but the interface has methods like this, that have other interfaces as methods.

```
public void setScoreStrategy(IScoreStrategy iScoreStrategy) {

}
public IScoreStrategy getScoreStrategy() {
    return null;
}
public ITestStatistics getTestStatistics() {
    return null;
}
public IQuestion getQuestion(int i) throws TestException {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question--the same way you implement any other getter/setter? They're just methods, methods specify parameter type(s) and return value type. You pass in, and return, something that matches the type signature.

Comment: return an instance

Comment: @DaveNewton Something like this?
     

`IScoreStrategy Score;
      public void setScoreStrategy(IScoreStrategy Score) {
        this.Score=Score;
    }
`

Comment: Best way to implement getters and setters is to make your IDE do it for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you deal with the regular fields in class:

Assumingv you have `scoreStrategy` and `testStatistics` fields:

```
public void setScoreStrategy(IScoreStrategy iScoreStrategy) {
    this.scoreStrategy = scoreStrategy;
}
public IScoreStrategy getScoreStrategy() {
    return scoreStrategy;
}
public ITestStatistics getTestStatistics() {
    return testStatistics;
}
// ...
```

Comment: `scoreStrategy = scoreStrategy` does not seem very useful